# Loading Javascript (google Charts) file to html using django

Tags: javascript, django, google-visualization

I'm struggling trying to load a google chart from a static file to an html using Django. I am able to load other javascript files using `{% load static %}`. Also, I'm capable to display the chart if I embed the javascript file into the html file:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% load static %}


{% block content %}
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

  <!-- JumboTron -->
  <div class="container">
      <div class="center-block">
        <div id="curve_chart"></div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" id=demo>
    let data_from_django = {{ object_list|safe }};
    CHART WORKING    
    function drawChart() {
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
      chart.draw(data, options);

      }
  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

However, if I embed the javascript code in `<script type="application/json" src="{% static 'js/load_data.js' %}"></script>`, and having loaded `static`, the code is never executed.

I've tried to put the the javascript file also inside the header, but it's still not loading. Any insights of anything i could be missing?

**Update**

See `load_data.js` :

```
$(function () {

let data_from_django = {{ object_list|safe }};
let dataValues=data_from_django["dataValues"];
let dataBacktest=data_from_django["dataBacktest"];

var googledata = [];
for(let i=0, size=dataValues.length; i<size; i++){
  var kline=dataValues[i]
  var value=kline["average"];  
  var date = new Date(kline["date"]);
  var googlekline = [date, value];
  googledata.push(googlekline);
}

google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'value');
  data.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'

  data.addRows(googledata);

  var options = {
    title: 'Price Chart',
    hAxis: {
      format: 'MMM, dd, yyyy, HH:mm'
    },
    explorer: {
      actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],
      axis: 'horizontal',
      maxZoomIn: 100.0
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    width: $(window).width()*0.75,
    height: $(window).height()*0.5
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

  }

});
```

Comment: If you view the source code of your file, is your {% static %} tag linking to the location of your .js file correctly? If so, when you navigate to the URL of your .js file, does it display properly?

Comment: @Sam, you are right! I didn't realise that by changing it to `application/json`, the file is not loaded anymore. However, as mentioned in the comment for the answer from @Sourav, then the django data is not correctly loaded. I get the error *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {*. And then nothing is displayed

Comment: I think that error is happening because of the line containing your template variable: `{{ object_list|safe }}`. Since you're using an include, Django is not properly replacing `{{ object_list|safe }}` with an object, and your Javascript file is reading it literally. To fix, you'll need to set a js variable in your standard file (no include) and then pass it to your included script.

Comment: that makes sense, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems are occurring here:

1. You are including the file as 'application/json', when you should be including it as 'text/javascript'. `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/load_data.js' %}"></script>`
2. You are attempting to use a Django template variable inside an included .js file. Django isn't passing the template context to your .js file, so it's rendering as actual code and Javascript is throwing an error (`let data_from_django = {{ object_list|safe }};` is not valid Javascript). You should define the variable in your base file using a Django template tag, and then pass that variable to your included script.